# GN: Can we do backface culling for points/instances?

Tags: camera, geometry-nodes, faces, geometry, instances

With Geometry Nodes, is it possible to create a *backface culling* type effect for instancing faces? That is, prevent faces the camera will never see from populating with instances?

Really the question should be: can we prevent such faces from populating with *points*? Since the instances rely on the points. This would be for a setup using the **Distribute Points on Faces** node.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can accomplish that by calculating the dot product of the normal of the face and the location of the camera:

[image]

The result from the dot product calculation will be a float between -1 and 1. -1 if the vectors are the exact inverse of each other (back) and 1 if the vectors match exactly (front).

Add a *Compare* node set to *Greater Than* after the dot product if you want to tweak the selection a bit. Might be needed if some of your instances "pops" in from nowhere.

Comment: This is excellent! It will be useful for many situations, even beyond the use I originally intended.